# Where to store an object I need the whole session and I need the possibility to update it, while also updating it in the database?

Tags: java, database, jsp, object, store

The Object is the logged in user with some objects related to him. I would like to keep the traffic on the database to a minimum. I need a proper solution to do this. I use JSP-Code without Scriptlets, with Servlets and I get the object through JPA. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Please clarify your question. "Where to store" - you already answered: in a database? Do you mean where does the code with responsibility for storing go? Some app servers will use a Database for HttpSession persistence, no need to write any code. Can you use that facility?

Comment: I mean where to store in my session, and how to update it in the application and the database easily, without always getting the whole object again from the database. Right now its stored in the session and I access it with
<c:out value="${sessionScope.user.name}" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your object to the [HttpSession](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) via the methods `setAttribute(...)` and retrieve it via `getAttribute(...)`

So your code (in a servlet) would look something like that:

```
final String CURRENT_USER_KEY = "CURRENT_USER";

EntityManager em; // somewhere initialized
Integer userid; //  somewhere initialized

HttpSession session =  httpServletRequest.getSession();
User user = session.getAttribute(CURRENT_USER_KEY);

if(user == null){
  User user = em.find(User.class, userId);
  session.setAttribute(CURRENT_USER_KEY, user);
}

// perform further actions on your user
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I have (except the EntityManager is in a service), do I have to do em.find() everytime I changed something on the userobject and what exactly is find doing?

Comment: The find statment will retrieve a `User` from your DB. If you change something in the user object, you can store your changes in the user object that is hold in your session and also send to the DB (via `merge(..)`). In my opinion it is not necessary to load the user again.

Answer (score 2):

If you store the data to the session like powerMicha suggested, you have to make sure that the data you are storing is serializable. Otherwise you might get some weird behavior as some Webcontainers save the session data to disk via serialization if they need the memory for other things.